# Upgrading the version of Kivy that is installed on a phone?

Tags: android, upgrade, kivy

How do you change the version of kivy installed on your device? I am getting the error:

> Exception: The version of Kivy installed on this system is too old.
>   (You have 1.8.0, but the application requires 1.9.0.

I tried recreating the whole deployable with `buildozer android clean` before deploying with `buildozer android debug deploy` but this didn't resolve the error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `kivy==master` in the requirements line of the buildozer.spec.

Comment: Just for others, because it is an unusual form, the whole line should read something like:  `requirements = kivy==master`

Comment: I am curious as to why this error would suddenly start to occur for me, when simply having 'kivy' in the requirements line was fine for ... well, years